# emulator won't start in android studio for hours

Tags: android-studio, emulation

I know this question has already been asked but I gone through all the answers and can't find appropriate solution.

whenever I run any app it shows **Waiting for device.
  C:\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus5 -netspeed full -netdelay none** and emulator doesn't       start for hours.

- when I click the run icon on avd manager nothing happens.
- I have tried changing the RAM size to 768 MB as mentioned in a post... and tried deleting old avds and creating new ones but nothing works.
- emulators worked well with ecllipse but not in studio.

please suggest something to sort this out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have "use host gpu" enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution...
I installed HAXM on my system and my emulators are finally working .... [check the link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x)

Do check the prerequisites before installation